# How to get vuetify style tags autocompletion in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, vuetify.js

Im using vuetify and intellij editor - and cannot make autocomplete to work

I have added vuetify css and js like below

`preferences > templates and languages > (added paths to vuetify css and js)`

Comment: Eg: <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center fill-height> - how can intellij autocomplete grid-list-md text-xs-center fill-height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vuetify components are supported since 2017.3.2 (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28318#comment=27-2578795) - just make sure that vuetify is installed in your project (`npm i vuetify --save`) and [Vue.js](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9442-vue-js) plugin is installed and enabled.

[image]

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/working-with-vue-js-in-webstorm/ for more info.

Vuetify mixins and directives are not yet supported, please follow [WEB-30070](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30070) for updates

Comment: directive support would be key to use of vuetify